# Mounting an additional hard drive, guide question

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I am adding an additional hard drive following this guide which uses gparted. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

However there is a portion I dont understand (sorry I am very much a beginner):

after `sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab`

it mentions adding the code below

```
  /dev/sdb1    /media/mynewdrive   ext3    defaults     0        2
```

Specifically I want to know what I should use after /dev/***. The guide uses sbd1. Also what are the 0 2 for? I want to make sure that this does not alter anything that I currently have.

Comment: `man fstab` should explain everything in detail.

Comment: `man fstab` is the command to display the reference **man**ual page for `fstab` (or file system table).  It's a reference manual for your system.  Field 5 is the dump parameter (use 0 as it's very rarely used), Field 6 is a `fsck` (file system check) parameter for ordering; 0 usually for key system drives, 2 for less system-critical data drives.  Rather than a device (/dev/sdb1) I'd suggest using the UUID (unique ID) which you can get from `blkid` once formatted; I'd also use ext4.  sda = first drive, sdb=second drive, the number is partition - but these values can change if you change BIOS/hw

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as per first comment, you can get full details with `man fstab`, or the command to display the reference manual page for `fstab` (file system table).

`man fstab` will tell you

> ```
>    The fifth field (fs_freq).
>           This  field  is used by dump(8) to determine which filesystems need to be dumped.  Defaults to zero (don't
>           dump) if not present.
>
>    The sixth field (fs_passno).
>           This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the order in which filesystem checks are  done  at  boot  time.
>           The  root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.  Other filesystems should have a fs_passno
>           of 2.  Filesystems within a drive will be checked sequentially, but filesystems on different  drives  will
>           be  checked  at  the  same time to utilize parallelism available in the hardware.  Defaults to zero (don't
>           fsck) if not present.
> ```

Field 5 is the dump parameter (use 0 as it's very rarely used)

Field 6 is a `fsck` (file system check) parameter for ordering; 0 usually for key system drives, 2 for less system-critical data drives.

Rather than a device (/dev/sdb1) I'd suggest using the UUID (unique ID) which you can get from `blkid` once formatted; I'd also use ext4. sda = first drive, sdb=second drive, the number is partition - but these values can change if you change BIOS/UEFI/settings or add/change hardware.

eg.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/var/crash$   sudo blkid
/dev/sda2: UUID="4f59600e-1f6b-4e3a-a466-941a2168e327" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-02"
/dev/sda1: UUID="afa7971f-3dd5-4b30-9c98-0af3e56a6f2b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-01"
/dev/sda4: UUID="06863296-81b3-4263-8665-21f1864fa399" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-04"
/dev/sda5: UUID="5b4267e5-8b90-4f6b-84b0-c4ee9d5e104d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="ba0dca2e-0799-4340-b565-a649842c8a69" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-06"
```

results in a file system entry for one of my partitions as

```
UUID=ba0dca2e-0799-4340-b565-a649842c8a69       /more           xfs             defaults        0 2
```

/more is what I've called "more space", which in my case is an encrypted (XFS not EXT) home partition for my other [dual-booted] Ubuntu system.  The UUID or Universally Unique Identifier being much more exact than sda6 which is all `lsblk` would tell me

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/var/crash$   lsblk
   ..redacted as only for example ..
└─sda6   8:6    0  53.8G  0 part /more
```

Comment: +1, particularly for "Rather than a device (/dev/sdb1) I'd suggest using the UUID (unique ID) which you can get from blkid once formatted; I'd also use ext4."

Comment: so I would want to add UUID=***   /media/mynewdrive   ext4    defaults     0        2 ?

Comment: Yep, assuming *** was your valid UUID

Comment: worked like a charm. You all are awesome!